# Showing the Type Hint for a @property data descriptor in help documents

Tags: python-3.5, python-3.6

For the following class:

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, title, author):
        self._title = title
        self._author = author

    @property
    def title(self) -> str:
        """Retrieve the book's title"""
        return self._title

    def author(self) -> str:
        """Retrieve the book's author"""
        return self._author
```

Invoking `help(Book)` returns the following documentation (abbreviated):

```
class Book(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  author(self) -> str
 |      Retrieve the book's author
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  title
 |      Retrieve the book's title
```

Note that the `author` method shows the type hint `-> str`, letting the user know that the author's name is a string.  The `title` property, on the other hand, shows no such hint.

Apart from simply adding the property's type into the docstring for the property, which allows for the code and documentation to diverge, is their any way to add the type hint to the property, so that `help()` will display the type for the property?